# How to add Bootstrap's enable-cssgrid Variable in Package.json

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, npm, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I have a project using Bootstrap and need to enable Bootstrap's cssgrid when the user runs [npm install] so I need to add this in package.json

-- Package.json

```
{
 "name": "PROJECT",
 "description": "DESC",
 "dependencies": {
   "backbone": "^1.4.1",
   "bootstrap": "^5.3.0-alpha1", // Need to add enable-cssgrid variable here!!
   "jquery": "^3.6.3"
  }
}
```

How to solve that so the client can get the correct Bootstrap module?